# System.Data.DuplicateNameException

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to read an xml file into a datagridview using c# and im having this error (System.Data.DuplicateNameException: 'A Relation named 'database_table' already belongs to this DataSet.') on the line **ds.ReadXml(opf.FileName);**

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
            opf.Filter = "XML File | *.xml";
            opf.FileName = "";

            if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(opf.FileName);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Record"];
            }
        }
```

I tried doing

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Remove("database_table");
ds.ReadXml(opf.FileName);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Record"];
```

still received the same error

Here is the XML File

```
 <!--
- Database: 'sialabact'
-->
<database name="sialabact">
    <!-- Table studentinfo -->
    <table name="studentinfo">
        <column name="Stud_No">20-1399</column>
        <column name="FirstName">Al-Sharief</column>
        <column name="LastName">Dinglasa</column>
        <column name="Section">SBIT3E</column>
    </table>
    <table name="studentinfo">
        <column name="Stud_No">21-4874</column>
        <column name="FirstName">Ryan</column>
        <column name="LastName">Wibowo</column>
        <column name="Section">SFIT4A</column>
    </table>
    <table name="studentinfo">
        <column name="Stud_No">19-2317</column>
        <column name="FirstName">Mark</column>
        <column name="LastName">Gallego</column>
        <column name="Section">BAENT3C</column>
    </table>
    <table name="studentinfo">
        <column name="Stud_No">20-1114</column>
        <column name="FirstName">Carlo</column>
        <column name="LastName">Enrile</column>
        <column name="Section">SBIT3M</column>
    </table>
</database>
```

This XML file was exported from MySQL

Comment: I assume your xml contains multiple records with the value "database_table". But we have no way of checking this if you don't include the xml file

Comment: Sorry, there it's uploaded

Comment: I just loaded this into a new project and it didnt give me any exceptions, if you have extra fields in your xml they might be the cause of the exception

Comment: May I ask what you IDE or tools you used to boot up the project?

Comment: I started a new winforms application using .NET 6. I made no further changes